# Plotly Heatmap not compatible with Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, kaggle

I have a problem with Plotly. First of all my code:

```
data=go.Heatmap(z=z, x=df[numerical].columns.values, y=df[numerical].columns.values, 
                type='heatmap', colorscale = 'Viridis', reversescale = False)

layout = go.Layout(title='Pearson Correlation of numerical features',
                   xaxis = dict(ticks='', nticks=36),
                   yaxis = dict(ticks='' ),
                   width = 900, height = 900)


fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='labelled-heatmap')
```

This code runs in my kaggle notebook without any problem. If I import this code to my jupyter notebook. I get the following error:

```
 Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Heatmap: 'type'
```

When I delete the type attribute I get the following error:

```
 Invalid value of type 'plotly.graph_objs._heatmap.Heatmap' received for the 'data' property of 
    Received value
```

As I am quite new to programming I hope the question doesnt seem stupid to you. But do you got any idea a) why the same code is running in a kaggle notebook without any problem but has issues with jupyter and b) what can I do to get this fixed?

Comment: What version of Plotly you are currently using on your own laptop? What version on kaggle notebook? They are likely to be different.

Comment: Thanks alot! It was obviously the old version I used. No everything runs without any problem. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely to be a mismatch between the version of Plotly on kaggle and on your laptop.

Please, update the version on your laptop by:

```
pip install -U plotly
```